# XML Type Conflict in JAXB (CXF/WebServices)

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, cxf, cxf-codegen-plugin

I am trying to run CXF WebService on Tomcat. When I deploy the WAR file, I get the following error:

```
        Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:354)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:469)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:693)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:529)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:262)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:199)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:103)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:168)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:460)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:338)
        ... 36 more
    Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://logicalprovisioning.gtt.com/gtc/processorder}objectFactory". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.gtt.logicalprovisioning.gtc.processorder.ObjectFactory
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.gtt.logicalprovisioning.utilities.symboltabledata.ObjectFactory
Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://logicalprovisioning.gtt.com/gtc/processorder}objectFactory". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.gtt.logicalprovisioning.utilities.symboltabledata.ObjectFactory
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.gtt.cio.commonheader.v3.ObjectFactory
]
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:226)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:372)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
        at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:345)
        at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:343)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
        at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.createContext(JAXBContextCache.java:343)
        at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.getCachedContextAndSchemas(JAXBContextCache.java:245)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.createJAXBContextAndSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:497)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:352)
        ... 47 more
    Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://logicalprovisioning.gtt.com/gtc/processorder}objectFactory". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.gtt.logicalprovisioning.gtc.processorder.ObjectFactory
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.gtt.logicalprovisioning.utilities.symboltabledata.ObjectFactory
Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://logicalprovisioning.gtt.com/gtc/processorder}objectFactory". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.gtt.logicalprovisioning.utilities.symboltabledata.ObjectFactory
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.gtt.cio.commonheader.v3.ObjectFactory

        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:76)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:441)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:273)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:109)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1126)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:135)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:211)
```

I generated the JAVA classes from WSDLs/XSDs using CXF plugins. This code worked earlier when I was on JDK8, but I moved my laptop to JDK15 recently. The code was left untouched for 6 months. I am wondering if the change in JDK had something to do with it or not. But I would like to get it to work on JDK15. Any suggestions would be helpful. If you need some more information, please do let me know.

Comment: Do you have more than 1 WSDLs/XSDs? Do two of them have the same target namespace? That's a big no-no. One WSDLs/XSDs per namespace, and one namespace per WSDLs/XSDs.

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of XSDs, about 40 of them and about 15 WSDL files. But i pretty certain that none of them share the same namespace.

Comment: But all the types from a namespace become a class in a package, i.e. namespace = package, so how come packages `com.gtt.logicalprovisioning.gtc.processorder` and `com.gtt.logicalprovisioning.utilities.symboltabledata` both have namespace `http://logicalprovisioning.gtt.com/gtc/processorder`? Because that is what the error message says, if you read it in detail.